# Doctrine - "automatically" delete children collection elements, when calling setter on parent

Tags: doctrine, entity

So, in my app, that uses Doctrine, I have entities Polls and PollAnswers. PollAnswers are linked to Polls as ManyToOne:

```
class PollAnswers
{
    /**
     * @var \Polls
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Polls", inversedBy="answers", fetch="LAZY")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="poll_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $poll;
```

When I add/delete/update poll answers from UI, I run next code:

```
    $answers = new ArrayCollection;
    foreach ($_POST['answers'] as $key => $answer)
    {
        $poll_answer = $em->getRepository(PollAnswers::class)->find($_POST['answers_ids'][$key]) ?: new PollAnswers;

        $poll_answer->setPoll($poll);
        $poll_answer->setAnswer($answer);

        $answers[]=$poll_answer;
    }

    $poll->setAnswers($answers);

    $em->persist($entity);
    $em->flush();
```

**But then, if poll answer was deleted from UI, it stays in database.** So, in addition I have to write such "ugly" piece of code:

```
    foreach ($poll->getAnswers() as $answer)
        if (!$answers->contains($answer))
            $em->remove($answer);
```

Can I somehow avoid adding this "ugly" piece? So, when I do setAnswers($answers), Doctrine automatically finds removed/missing entities and deletes them? I am sure, there is an "elegant" way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Poll` entity set `orphanRemoval=true` for `PollAnswers`, something like this:

```
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PollAnswers", ... , orphanRemoval=true)
```

See the docu [here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/working-with-associations.html#orphan-removal).

Comment: This maybe the way, but doesn't work as expected, when I add orphanRemoval=true. It removes any existing child entities. So, let's say, I had next answers entities: A, B, C. And I add D. As a result, only answer D is present, A,B,C got removed :(

Comment: In your code I only see you call `setAnswers`, in this case what you described (A,B,C get removed) would be the expected behaviour. Are you really calling `addPollAnswer` ?

Comment: In my setAnswers I do $this->answers=$answers; And $answers contain ArrayCollection with "old" answers (A,B,C that I find using $em->getRepository(PollAnswers::class)->find) and newly added answer D. So, why would A,B,C be deleted, if I send A,B,C,D to setAnswers()?

Comment: I have updated my setAnswers() from

`$this->answers=$answers;`

to

`$this->getAnswers()->clear(); foreach ($answers as $answer) $this->getAnswers()->add($answer);`

and now with `orphanRemoval=true` it works as expected!